# Can VS 2010 check/update header files automatically?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, header-files

That's pretty much my question: can VS 2010 check and update header files in C++ code automatically? And can VS 2010 automatically generate a cpp file from a header file, saving you the time to copy the function definitions from the header file? I mean, can it figure that there's no implementation for some method and generate an empty stub from the declaration found in the header file?

Thanks!
CFP.

Comment: Hmya, the Class Wizard can do this.  You ought to take a look at Visual Assist for the real hand-holding stuff.

Comment: One of the minor issues is that default arguments go in the header, not the implementation. It makes more sense to me to have a "create stub in .cpp" option, that's an information-stripping operation.

Comment: @MSalters +1; True, indeed =) And it would be great if it could do it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this feature does not exist in the Visual Studio C++ implementation.  Changes to a header file must be manually propagated to the source file and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Pity VS can't do that =)

Comment: So the next question is does any of the available plug ins do it?

Comment: @Fire lancer: Seems there are none, I searched before... I thought it might be due to VS being able to do so, so I asked =)