# C++ source code text editor with .h .cpp sync support

Tags: c++, editor, code-assist

Is there a (free) text editor that automatically synchronizes method declarations so that if I update method definition in a .CPP then its declaration in the .H gets updated automatically (and vice versa)?

Better yet, present the class' source code in a single editor view and generate .H and .CPP from it automatically.

MS Visual Studio has some support for that, but its not free.

Comment: MS Visual Studio _Express_ is free (beer-free rather than speech-free but I think that's what you meant). I don't know if the express version has that feature but it's probably worth checking out.

Comment: Where is that feature in Visual Studio? I've never seen it before, and neither have [these folks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764460/can-vs-2010-check-update-header-files-automatically). It *is* a component of Visual Assist X, as I understand, but that's an add-on to VS, not part of it.

Comment: I prefer not having the header automatically updated: it keeps me in control of when dependencies change (a recompile could be triggeredm even if you hit undo after the fact); also it encourages being scrupulous about only including public interface in the header at all times. A good design goes a long ways, I suppose

Comment: Such automatic features also will mess with you code intendations. But if you manage to find a utility that does that with minimal impact, I bet it's never going to be free. But then necessity is the mother of invention. Maybe try to create one yourself if you fail to find one?

Answer (score 2):

If you're editing a stable library then *you do not want this*, because you really care about when you change an interface -- since it probably means you're breaking compatibility with something else.

If you're in the rapid-prototyping stage, then why not put all your definitions in the header file, and worry about separating them into the implementation file later.

That said, I know of nothing that actually does what you want, so:

If you want to implement this, I'd suggest writing a third header&implementation file (that the compiler never sees), which you actually edit, and then adding a pre-compilation stage that automatically splits it into header and source. You'll probably want to annotate include directives to show where they need to be.

Comment: No, I want this for brand new projects, and I am willing to accept  any special indentation/formatting quirks needed to support the automatic editing functionality.

Comment: Good point about the compatibility check. This is something that e.g. Java does not have, so there have to be tools like http://wiki.netbeans.org/SigTest

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [makeheaders](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/mkhdr/). It does not provide parallel editing features, but instead generates headers from your source files.

Answer (score 2):

KDevelop has some support for it. Not flawless, but it is pretty good. One of my projects is cross platform, and whenever I need to expand my code, I prefer KDevelop over Visual Studio.